# HealthVault class structure

Tags: healthvault

I have just started evaluating Microsoft's HealthVault API today.

I've found some stuff online (mainly MS) but it seems to be mostly marketing blurb, so if there are any Healthvault programmers who feel they have a good (i.e. technical) resource, I'd be grateful if they could share it. I have found and downloaded the nuget package so am looking through that for leads too.

I have a more specific question. The first thing I did was to lookup  `Microsoft.Health.ItemTypes.BloodGlucoseMeasurement`, just because glucose measurements will be my primary interest. Inherits from a class called `Measurement<T>`, has a double property called `Value`. All makes sense so far. What I don't see, however, is a variable to store a unit associated with the value. Neither in the base class or its child.

Something like glucose has a couple of different standard units, depending on where you are in the world, so I was wondering, just at a high level, how Healthvault supprts different units (for glucose in particular)?

I'm hoping to work in C# and .NET (latest-ish), but at this stage I just want to understand how Healthvault hangs together.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

To answer my specific question: HealthVault stores glucose values in a fixed unit which is mmol/l.

BloodGlucostMeasurement class has a DisplayValue property. however. This leads to a class which *does* support specifying different units. So my UI could take, say, 100 mg/dl (the other common unit) and store the converted value.

I can see the value in having a single usit to actually store the data, but just looking at the geography I am surprised that Microsoft adopted mmol/l.